# How to get symfony2 application execution time?

Tags: symfony, profiler, execution-time

I need to get symfony2 application execution time in twig or controller, and to store it in mysql database. How I can do this? It is available in web profiler toolbar, but I don't know how to access it.

Comment: Do you need it in `dev` and `prod` environments? Since the toolbar is only present in `dev` environment, you'll have to find another way.

Comment: I need it in prod environment. I think it is possible, because if I create log in form to enable user log in, later I can from twig template access logged in user with app.user.username.

Comment: Create a listener for kernel.request and kernel.terminate events, storing the startime and then updating it with the endtime.

Comment: any example how to do that?

Comment: Solved it with microtime() function. At the beginning of the controller I put starttime and at the end endtime. I did not count the time spent on display in twig, but on the basis of previous tests error is of the order 0.5 - 1s

Comment: For what purposes need you to see time, if 0.5-1s doesn't matter?

Answer (score 4):

If you're only accounting for the time the controller takes,
you can use the Stopwatch component:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/stopwatch.html

```
use Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\Stopwatch;

public function indexAction()
{
    $stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    // Start event named 'eventName'
    $stopwatch->start('eventName');
    // ... some code goes here
    $event = $stopwatch->stop('eventName');
    // get total duration (but see the docs for more info)
    $timeTaken = $event->getDuration();   // Returns the event duration, including all periods

     ...

}
```